# SELECT a datetimeoffset field by datetime

Tags: sql, datetime, sql-server-2014, datetimeoffset

I have a table with a datetimeoffset field which is primary key. I want to filter my table with a datetime.

For example my table has:

```
2016-04-27 23:30:00.7684500 +03:00
2016-04-28 00:30:00.7684500 +03:00
```

In local time format, first row mean 2016-04-28 02:30:00 and second row means 2016-04-28 03:30:00. I mean two of them in date: 2016-04-28.

When I wanted to report transactions in date 2016-04-28, I get only second row.

```
declare @fromDate datetime
select @fromDate = '2016-04-28 00:00:00'
select * from MYTABLE where dto > @fromDate
```

Because, sql look at UTC time in datetimeoffset field.

I can get what I really want like this:

```
declare @fromDate datetime
select @fromDate = '2016-04-28 00:00:00'
select * from MYTABLE where CAST(dto as datetime) > @fromDate
```

First and second row are coming.

The question is: does performance suffer due to casting? System looking and casting every row (sequential read), even if dto is the primary key?

Is there any better way?

Many thanks...

Comment: Tag the dbms used. (That code doesn't look like ANSI SQL...)

Comment: Thank you. It's MS SQL server 2014.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely ... I would recommend adding a Calculated Field to the table.  This way, the conversion takes place automatically in SQL and there is not CAST or CONVERT needed in the query.  Do a search on Calculated Field and insert your code

```
CONVERT(DATETIME, dto, 109)
```

or

```
TRY_CONVERT(DATETIME, dto, 109)
```

I would use TRY_CONVERT as you can specifically set the format of the DateTime for your new calculated field and if for some reason, dto is not a valid date, it will insert NULL as opposed to failing.

Answer (score 2):

If your offset (+3) is a constant, you can try this:

```
declare @fromDate datetime
select @fromDate = '2016-04-28 00:00:00'
select * from MYTABLE where dateadd(hour, 3, dto) > @fromDate
```

Or you can use `TODATETIMEOFFSET`

as follow:

```
select * from MYTABLE where TODATETIMEOFFSET(dto, '03:00') > @fromDate
```